# google's protorpc is broken (metaclass error)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, grpc

I'm trying to learn the basics of grpc, but using the example from [this appengine doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/protorpc/) results in the errors shown below.  I am using `Python 2.7.11` on a Mac, in a fresh virtualenv.

When using the latest versions of `protorpc` and `six` I get one error, and when downgrading `six` to version `1.10.0` as suggested by others on the web when googling this problem, I get a different error.  Both errors are shown below.

**Contents of hello.py file (copied directly from the doc)**

```
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote
from protorpc.wsgi import service

package = 'hello'

class HelloRequest(messages.Message):
    my_name = messages.StringField(1, required=True)

class HelloResponse(messages.Message):
    hello = messages.StringField(1, required=True)

class HelloService(remote.Service):

    @remote.method(HelloRequest, HelloResponse)
    def hello(self, request):
        return HelloResponse(hello='Hello there, %s!' % request.my_name)

# Map the RPC service and path (/hello)
app = service.service_mappings([('/hello.*', HelloService)])
```

**Running the latest pip modules (versions shown below):**

```
$ pip freeze
protorpc==0.11.1
six==1.11.0

$ python hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from protorpc import messages
  File "/tmp/grpc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/protorpc/messages.py", line 1146, in <module>
    class Field(six.with_metaclass(_FieldMeta, object)):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

**Running with downgraded `six` module (versions shown below):**

```
$ pip freeze
protorpc==0.11.1
six==1.10.0

$ python hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    from protorpc import remote
  File "/tmp/grpc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/protorpc/remote.py", line 117, in <module>
    from . import protobuf
  File "/tmp/grpc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/protorpc/protobuf.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .google_imports import ProtocolBuffer
ImportError: cannot import name ProtocolBuffer
```

Is there a magical combination of versions will make this example work, or if there is maybe the doc I am following is outdated and wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This was indeed broken; fix is in and I just released `0.12.0` with the fix.

Comment: thanks Craig, but its still failing for me with error message "ImportError: cannot import name ProtocolBuffer"

Comment: Two related comments:

1. Yes, it looks like the `remote` module still has some issues.
2. Rereading the first part of your question, note that grpc and protorpc have no real relationship.

Answer (score 0):

on my ancient system i encountered the same after an attempt to do a limited and useless upgrade.
after reading your question i understood what to check and found the magic combination:

```
protorpc-0.10.0-py2.7.egg
six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg
```

yes, and even better combination will come in a true upgrade.
thank you very much for the question and the answers alike.